# JOIN clause with WHERE

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, ms-access, oledb

Ive got 3 tables called Course, CourseCatogory, CourseCourseCatagory. CourseCourseCatagory is a junction table. I am trying to select courses that are linked to particular catogory using the junction table. This is my first time using a junction table and JOIN clause, I just don't know how to go about doing it. It would be highly appreciated if there's anything you could do to help me.

```
 public static courseDetails getSelectedCatogory(string Category)
        {
              courseDetails details = new courseDetails();

            using (OleDbConnection connection = getConnection())
            {
                string query = "SELECT CourseName, Description FROM CourseCourseCategory WHERE Category = @Category JOIN Course ON Course.ID = CourseCourseCategory.CourseID " +
                    "JOIN CourseCategory ON CourseCategory.ID = CourseCourseCategory.CourseCategoryID";

                OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, connection);
                OleDbParameter pram = new OleDbParameter("@CourseCategory", CourseCategory);
                command.Parameters.Add(pram);
                connection.Open();

                OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                while (reader.Read())
                {

                  courseDetails d = new courseDetails();

                  d.CourseName = reader["CourseName"].ToString();
                  d.Description = reader["Description"].ToString();

                    details = d;
                }



            }

            return details;
        }
```

Comment: Try moving the `WHERE` portion of your query to after the `JOIN`s.  It's invalid SQL to have it before then.

Comment: One of the easiest things to do is just to run these queries in your sql management studio rather than writing straight into code. That way, for example, you'll see anything blindingly obvious as to why it's not working straight away just through errors

Comment: In addition to @PinnyM 's comment on how to fix this, you should use your SQL client to debug SQL statements before you move then into a piece of software.  That way, you can isolate where the problem is and probably have an easier time testing.

Comment: It is a good idea to post the [error message](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) you get and not the vague "it doesn't work".

Comment: I moved the WHERE clause and it gave me "Syntax error in FROM clause."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get an understanding of how this works I suggest you start out like:

```
FROM Course c -- or with CourseCategory
```

then JOIN the junction table:

```
FROM Course c
JOIN CourseCourseCategory cc
    ON c.ID = cc.CourseID
```

then join CATEGORY with the junction table:

```
FROM Course c
JOIN CourseCourseCategory ccc
    ON c.ID = cc.CourseID
JOIN CourseCategory cc
    ON cc.ID = ccc.CourseCategoryID
```

Then add the where clause:

```
FROM Course c
JOIN CourseCourseCategory ccc
    ON c.ID = cc.CourseID
JOIN CourseCategory cc
    ON cc.ID = ccc.CourseCategoryID
WHERE cc.Category = @Category
```

I assume that Category is an attribute of CourseCategory (always use a qualifier since it will make the code easier to read and understand). Finally, select from the relation you defined:

```
SELECT c.CourseName, c.Description
FROM Course c
JOIN CourseCourseCategory ccc
    ON c.ID = cc.CourseID
JOIN CourseCategory cc
    ON cc.ID = ccc.CourseCategoryID
WHERE cc.Category = @Category
```

Comment: I have tried all the solution above and in each case i got a syntax error. Usually one that says "Syntax error in FROM clause.". I did a bit of research and it turns out that Access  requires parentheses in the FROM clause of any query which includes more that one join. So I used  the query designer in access to build a query with parentheses. Which as a result turned out like this, SELECT * FROM Course INNER JOIN (CourseCategory INNER JOIN CourseCourseCategory ON CourseCategory.ID = CourseCourseCategory.CourseCategoryID) ON Course.ID = CourseCourseCategory.CourseID WHERE Category = @Category

Comment: The query above works however despite using (* ) all, it only shows one record. Please help!

Comment: Add create table statements and insert statements for sample data that illustrates the problem. It is more or less impossible to tell why the query does not return the expected number of rows without that. FWIW, the * does not affect the number of rows, only the number of columns

Comment: I tested the query in access and the query worked fine which lead me to believe that there was something wrong with my code and it happen to be just that. Instead of using object data source i used sql data source and that fixed the problem. Thanks for all your help Lennart.