# How to do a count including not existing records?

Tags: sql, ms-access

How to do a count including not existing records, which should have '0' as the count?

Here is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE SURVEY
(year CHAR(4),
cust CHAR(2));
INSERT INTO SURVEY VALUES ('2011', 'AZ');
INSERT INTO SURVEY VALUES ('2011', 'CO');
INSERT INTO SURVEY VALUES ('2012', 'ME'); 
INSERT INTO SURVEY VALUES ('2014', 'ME'); 
INSERT INTO SURVEY VALUES ('2014', 'CO');
INSERT INTO SURVEY VALUES ('2014', 'ME'); 
INSERT INTO SURVEY VALUES ('2014', 'CO');
```

I've tried this, but of course it is missing zero counts:

```
select cust, year, count(*) as count from SURVEY
group by cust, year
```

I want to have this result:

```
+------+---------+--------+
| cust |    year |  count |
+------+---------+--------+
| AZ   |    2011 |  1     |
| AZ   |    2012 |  0     |
| AZ   |    2014 |  0     |
| CO   |    2011 |  1     |
| CO   |    2012 |  0     |
| CO   |    2014 |  2     |
| ME   |    2011 |  0     |
| ME   |    2012 |  1     |
| ME   |    2014 |  2     |
+------+---------+--------+
```

please note:

- My table has many records (~10k with different 'cust')
- years may not be sequential (for example 2013 is skipped)
- over time i may have 2015, 2016 and so on
- the actual query will be executed in MS_ACCESS'2010 (not sure if its matter)

please help, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want a count for every cust x year combination with a zero when no survey record exists. If this is the case you will need two more tables: customers and years then do something like:

```
    select leftside.cust, leftside.year, count(survey.cust) from
(select * from customers, years) as leftside left join survey
on leftside.cust = survey.cust and 
leftside.year = survey.year 
group by leftside.cust, leftside.year
```

Comment: the sqlfiddle was helpful, fixed it  and edited the question, seems to work ok now

Comment: yes, thank you, it worked. it also works in ms-access!

Answer (score 0):

```
select cust, year, (select count(cust) from survey) as count
  from SURVEY
group by cust, year
```

But this query will return count of all records, without group condition.

Comment: not quite what i was looking for, need to have correct count.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a domain table for years and customers:

```
select y.year, c.cust, count(s.year) as cnt
from customer as c
cross join year as y
left join survey as s
    on s.year = y.year
    and s.cust = c.cust
group by y.year, c.cust
```

If ms-access don't have cross join, you can do the same with:

```
from customer as c
join year as y
    on 1 = 1
```

If you don't have domain tables you will somehow need to "invent" the domains since you cant create something from nothing.

Comment: hmm, i am getting wrong count AZ getting 1 count for 2012, should be zero, see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bce5e/1

Comment: Oh, sorry. It should be count(s.year). I'll update the answer

Comment: sql code worked, but can you please clarify ms-access code. i am getting errors, is this what you mean? `select y.year, c.cust, count(s.year) as cnt
from customer as c
join year as y
    on 1 = 1
left join survey as s
    on s.year = y.year
    and s.cust = c.cust
group by y.year, c.cust`

Comment: Yes, I don't have access so I can't verify, but that is the idea

Comment: In http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29098795/join-clause-with-where/29099373?noredirect=1#comment46431670_29099373 someone suggested that "Access requires parentheses in the FROM clause of any query which includes more that one join"

Answer (score 0):

If you have domain tables as others said, well and good. If you have to depend only on data in your table, the below query will do that for you.

```
select cp.cust, cp.year, iif(isnull(sum(cnt)), 0, sum(cnt)) as count from
(select * from (
 (select distinct cust from survey) as c cross join
 (select distinct year from survey) as y)
) cp left join
(select *, 1 as cnt from survey) s on cp.cust=s.cust and cp.year=s.year
group by cp.cust, cp.year
order by cp.cust,cp.year
```

Instead of `iif(isnull(sum(cnt)), 0, sum(cnt))`, you can use `coalesce(sum(cnt),0)` if that works. In MS Access use `iif` function and in other databases `coalesce` works.

Comment: instead of using `,` I replaced with `cross join`.. now it seems working http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/eef78/7

Comment: please check the sqlfiddle link in previous comment and see if that is working. or is it not working in MS Access?